# How much time will the Ethereum wallet take to sync for the first time

Tags: myetherwallet

I downloaded and installed Ethereum wallet for windows 64 on my machine. When I tried to launch it for the first time, it started downloading the blocks .Already many hours have passed by but the download of the chain structure seems to be never ending . I would like to create new account and get some ether into my wallet . How long with this sync up take and can I proceed to create a new account , while the sync up is going on in the background
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How long with this sync up take?

Depending on disk write and download speed, it can take a while - it'll always be constantly syncing as you're now running essentially a full node, which is a copy of the blockchain.

> I would like to create new account and get some ether into my wallet.

Use a "light client", which is an application that uses a full node that is run by someone that is constantly syncing. A good platform to use is https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet#httpswwwmyetherwalletcom which is a client side wallet that interacts with supported nodes (and once yours is fully synced, you can [set up your own node with MyEtherWallet](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-can-i-connect-to-a-custom-node?from_search=true) - and even [run it offline](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-run-myetherwallet-dot-com-offline-slash-locally?from_search=true)).

Alternatively, whilst you wait for the blockchain to sync and you don't want to use MyEtherWallet, you can set up an account on an exchange and buy some ether ($ETH) and store it there until you have your own wallet configured.

<sup>I must note that I'm not a representative of MEW, but I do use it daily.</sup>